# Read text file from upload and save it again in text file using django

Tags: python, django

How can I read the data of a text file from a form like file uploading by selecting a text file and then read the data. After reading, i will populate the data from my database and save it as text file while the user will select where to save it. Is this possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you written any code as yet ? The process is pretty simple - 
1. Include a FileField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield). Ensure that you have set up upload_to correctly 
2. Read from upload_to location and do file manipulations 
3. Expose the file to be downloaded via MEDIA_URL (assuming MEDIA_ROOT is where you have set up your uploads to go to).

Hope this helps.